# How to create references to objects created in a loop?

Tags: java

I'm sure this question has been asked but I cannot find it (on SO or Google) for my life.

How can I most effectively create a reference to multiple objects that I create in a loop? 
In this specific case, I am using Swing to add JButtons to a GridLayout.

```
int numOfButtons = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < numOfButtons; i++){
    add(new JButton("" + i));}
```

If later I want to change the text on the buttons, how would I do so? Say, if I wanted to change button number 8:

```
buttonEight.setText("DO NOT CLICK!!!);
```

How would I create a reference to the button with the 8 on it from `buttonEight`?

The only thing I can think of is creating a bunch of instance variables before the loop. Except... Well. Actually , that wouldn't work (I don't think)

Something that would do this:

```
JButton button8;
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfButtons; i++){

    button + i = new JButton(""+ i); 
    //like, if i = 8 then button + i gets me button8 to reference it or something?
    //obviously that doesn't work
    }

button8.setText("DO NOT CLICK!!!);
```

and also I'd be in trouble creating the right number of instance variables if numOfButtons is variable.

How should I do this?

Comment: This is a textbook use case for arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<JButton> list=new ArrayList<>();
int numOfButtons = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < numOfButtons; i++){
    JButton jb=new JButton("" + i);
    list.add(jb);
    add(jb);
}
```

Later (assuming you want to change the text of 8th button (which is 7 in list)):

```
list.get(7).setText("...");
```

The list only create a reference to JButton object. Then any change made to it will reflect on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you wanted to set the text of only the eighth button, you could use a conditional to single out that button:

```
for (int i=0;i<numOfButtons;i++) {
    if (i==7) {
        add(new JButton("DO NOT CLICK!");
    } else {
        add(new JButton(""+i);
    }
}
```

which will save memory space in your program than if you use an `ArrayList`.